# Connect to a WCF Service NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf

I am connecting to the WCF service with NetTcpBinding. I am stuck in framing the request from client.

I don't have the developer documentation but from the WSDL the request policy is

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="NetTcpBinding_AuthorizationWebService_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
        <msb:BinaryEncoding
            xmlns:msb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/mspolicy/netbinary1"/>
            <sp:TransportBinding
                xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <msf:SslTransportSecurity
                                xmlns:msf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/framing/policy"/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:TransportBinding>
                <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

With this, what should I pass for Transport?

I am passing as below, but it throws `System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: 'Access is denied.'`

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri);


ChannelFactory<IAuthorizationWebService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IAuthorizationWebService>(binding, address);

IAuthorizationWebService _clientProxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

var claims = _clientProxy.LoadClaims();
```

Any guidance, please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set the security mode to `None` on both server-side and client-side in code or web.config like below:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TcpBindingname" maxReceivedMessageSize="20480000" transferMode="Streamed" >
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```